Is Air Canada notorious?
Firstly, I'm not exactly sure if this should be posted as a question, but anyway I've actually been wondering about this for a long time now. My part of the story goes like this:
Me and my family went on a vacation to an Asian country. We took an direct international flight to our destination, and planned to return by Air Canada, with a stop in Vancouver. The problem is, the time window between the landing of the first leg's aircraft and the boarding of the final leg is only around 60 minutes. There were no other options when we booked our flight, so we thought we should put up with it. The first leg's aircraft, also operated by Air Canada, was delayed by some 20 minutes. As you can imagine, we were late, due to the delay, and also since the time frame is so narrow, and our luggage was heavy. Our movements were further impeded because I was constantly throwing up due to my airsickness. We were late by probably 10~20 minutes, and we had to wait some 7 hours sitting at the terminal, waiting for the next flight. That experience left us with PTSD and we never flew on Air Canada again.
My question is, does anyone have a similar experience? Is Air Canada known for delays + narrow time windows + an extremely long wait for the next flight? Or was our experience exceptionally bad and happen because we were unlucky? Finally, is the reputation of Air Canada bad? Is our decision on never choosing Air Canada again a reasonable and correct decision? OR, should we overcome our fears and give it another chance? I'll appreciate any suggestions on this. Thanks in advance, and please feel free to share your own past experiences with me!

This is too opinion based for this site. You will find that people have great and terrible experiences with a vast number of airlines. AC is definitely not among the worse, not even close when it comes it poor experiences. The minimum connection time is dictated by the airport, plus certain flights are not frequent, so all this is pretty common for a delay on the initial flight.

@Itai OK, thanks for the feedback, so how can I improve? Or do you suggest me to delete this question immediately before a cascade of downvotes?

I also had a not so good experience with AC with YVR connections to Asia, although not as bad as you. Had to run (literally) in one direction. But it's something to keep in mind when booking these tickets - I usually prefer connections of 3-4 hours at least when possible. Not always it's possible.

It will probably end up closed. What you can do is break some of the contents into new objectively answerable questions such as minimum connection time rules and feasibility, airline service consistency, etc. As an anecdote, years ago, I had backlisted Delta so that travel agents would never consider them for my trips after 4 out of 5 flights I took one summer had absurd delays (30min flight delayed by 6h... ) but a decade later, they got their act together and are consistently among timely airlines.

Are you sure there where no other options? Where did you book the flight? Note heavy baggage, family and airsickness are not standard, so they may target different people to be competitive compared direct flights. Also note they had extra costs: empty seats, and prepare new seats in new aircraft, so they will not do that (short connections) lightly. In any case we tend to avoid such short connection on intercontinental flights.

The minimum connection time for Domestic -> Vancouver -> International (non-US) is 60 minutes, according to Air Canada. As you had this for the original schedule, it was tight, but doable

Look, I fly AC all the time, and like most Canadians I hate them and complain about them ("we're not happy till you're not happy!") but the scenario you describe is not airline specific at all. Heavy carryon luggage that made you move slowly? Leftover airsickness that delayed your progress through a connection? These are highly unusual. Better to ask how to take these things into account when planning a trip than whether an airline is awful because you had one day of bad luck.

Saying that having to wait for a few hours left you with PTSD is probably an insult to people who have actually suffered real trauma (you know, with explosions, bullets flying, blood, injuries, deaths...). It may have been an annoying experience, but that's the risk with any connecting flight (or any flight, really!). Flights are delayed and connections are missed every day. If there had been no delay on the first flight, you would have made it. If you were not subject to severe travel sickness after your flight, you would probably have made it. (...)

(...) Your incoming flight was late, AC rebooked you on what was probably the next flight, they did their job. If you want more margin, take more margin (which would probably be the flight you got in the end).

really good point @jcaron. OP could have booked an 8 hour connection, but didn't want it. By booking the tighter connection they had a chance of avoiding that wait, so it might not even have been the wrong choice. The dice didn't land as desired, but that happens sometimes. (When an airline made me wait an extra 8 hours in Dublin after a delay like that, I went out and toured a castle for 5 or so of the hours, a lovely experience and Vancouver may not have castles but it has plenty you could have enjoyed.)

Air Canada has been voted best airline in North America eight times in the last ten years.  That may not make it a good airline, but it does mean all the other suck more, and no, it's not "notorious".

@DJClayworth It could be argued that they are notorious in a positive way!

You travelled all the way across the world in a matter of hours. At some point you had the inconvenience to have to wait a few hours. But apparently that was enough to leave PTSD (on the off-chance it's real, please seek medical help, not random strangers on the internet) and compel you to go scream your anger at the face of the internet. What's your question? "Does it happen often with this particular airline"? How will any answer help you, given that you've already decided not to fly with them anymore?

@njzk2 Perhaps PTSD is an exaggeration, but certainly we won't fly with Air Canada agian.

@LukeL perhaps indeed


Is Air Canada known for delays + narrow time windows + an extremely long wait for the next flight?

Not particularly.  It's a very common side effect of the "hub and spoke" approach to airline operations.  You ask whether anyone has had similar experiences; I've had similar experiences on several occasions, but never with Air Canada.

Or was our experience exceptionally bad and happen because we were unlucky?

It could have been worse: your new flight might have been the next day.

Yes there are lots of routes that airlines only fly once a day, and sometimes less often. Once weekly isn't unheard of, although in such cases you'd expect to be rerouted somehow.
